# How to override on .val() of a jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How can I override on val() method, not on all but on those ones that return by my plugin, for instance look at following sample:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.switch = function (action, options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
        }, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            $this.val = function(){
              return 10;
          }
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

I expect that `$("#some-id").switch().val()` returns `10` while it seems that it doesn't work.
I don't want to use `$.fn.val` to override on entire objects.
How should I achieve that?

Comment: Seems like a really counter-intuitive thing to do since anyone using  jQuery is very familiar with the default `val()` behavior, Changing it for specific elements only could lead to confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to set the plugin elements' `data` to something indicating that it's a plugin element, then change `$.fn.val` to invoke your custom logic if the element it was called on is a plugin element:

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.switch = function(action, options) {
    var settings = $.extend({}, options);

    this.each(function() {
      $(this).data('plugin-element', true);
    });
  };
  const origVal = $.fn.val;
  $.fn.val = function(newVal) {
    if (newVal) {
      return origVal.call(this, newVal);
    }
    return $(this).data('plugin-element')
      ? 10
      : origVal.call(this);
  }

})(jQuery);

$('div').switch();
console.log($('div').val());
console.log($('input').val());
$('input').val(33);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<input value=55>
```

But while this is possible, it's a *very* weird thing to do, and makes the codebase more fragile. Consider if there's a more elegant way to accomplish your objective.